# How to wrap all next elements until?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapall

I have following html:

```html
<div class="menuItem">Domů</div>
<div class="menuItem">O nás</div>
<div class="menuItem">Výzkum a vývoj</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Aplikace aktivního gumového prášku</b>
</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Odprašky</b>
</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Guma</b>
</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Zemědělství</b>
</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Potravinářství</b>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">Projekční činnost</div>
<div class="menuItem">Realizace</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>realizace podstránka</b>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">Kontakty</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve, is wrap each `.menuItem` and all next `.submenuItem` with `.menuSet`. Unhappily, the following js wraps the whole snippet instead of the set defined above.

```html
<div class="menuItem">Domů</div>
<div class="menuItem">O nás</div>
<div class="menuItem">Výzkum a vývoj</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Aplikace aktivního gumového prášku</b>
</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Odprašky</b>
</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Guma</b>
</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Zemědělství</b>
</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>Potravinářství</b>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">Projekční činnost</div>
<div class="menuItem">Realizace</div>
<div class="submenuItem"><b>realizace podstránka</b>
</div>
<div class="menuItem">Kontakty</div>
```

For make my intention more understandable, below I post the desired result:

```js
$(".menuItem").nextUntil(".menuItem").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='menuSet'></div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menuSet">
  <div class="menuItem">Domů</div>
</div>
<div class="menuSet">
  <div class="menuItem">O nás</div>
</div>
<div class="menuSet">
  <div class="menuItem">Výzkum a vývoj</div>
  <div class="submenuItem"><b>Aplikace aktivního gumového prášku</b>
  </div>
  <div class="submenuItem"><b>Odprašky</b>
  </div>
  <div class="submenuItem"><b>Guma</b>
  </div>
  <div class="submenuItem"><b>Zemědělství</b>
  </div>
  <div class="submenuItem"><b>Potravinářství</b>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menuSet">
  <div class="menuItem">Projekční činnost</div>
</div>
<div class="menuSet">
  <div class="menuItem">Realizace</div>
  <div class="submenuItem"><b>realizace podstránka</b>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menuSet">
  <div class="menuItem">Kontakty</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are selecting all the `menuItem`'s with class and than filtering from there, `wrapAll` will wrap your whole collection.

To solve this, one way would to be use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and iterate through the menuItems and than wrap them.

```
$(".menuItem").each(function (index) {
    $(this).nextUntil(".menuItem").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='menuSet'></div>");
});
```

### JSFiddle Demo

.

Comment: Consider to use `addBack()` instead of `andSelf()` which is deprecated as for jq1.8